# Unit test, mocking data from repository (IQueryable асинхронный)

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты

Всем привет, возникла проблема с вызовом метода.
Я создаю unit test и сейчас пытаюсь получить mock data из репозитория. Тут я получаю данные из файла JSON:

```
public static IQueryable<Reservation> GetBaseReservations()
{
    return JsonUtils.ConvertToObject<List<Reservation>>(JsonFiles.ReservationCardsReportRequest,
    JsonKeys.ReservationCardsReportRequest).AsQueryable();
}
```

А в этом методе я имитирую вызов данных из БД:

```
reservationRepository.Setup(mock => mock.GetReservationBaseQueryAsync(It.IsAny<ReportRequest>()))
                    .ReturnsAsync(GetBaseReservations());
```

Однако на данный момент, это синтаксически неверная конструкция, т.к. этот метод(GetReservationBaseQueryAsync) выглядит так:

```
Task<IQueryable<Reservation>> GetReservationBaseQueryAsync(ReportRequest reportRequest);
```

Моя проблема в том, что этот метод асинхронный и я не знаю как с этим методом правильно работать.
Т.е. в случае когда IQueryable (без Task!!!) Это бы выглядело следующим образом:

```
//if
//IQueryable<Reservation> GetReservationBaseQueryAsync(ReportRequest reportRequest);

//then
reservationRepository.Setup(mock => mock.GetReservationBaseQueryAsync(It.IsAny<ReportRequest>()))
                    .Returns(GetBaseReservations().BuildMock().Object);
```

Но тут как вы видите метод не асинхронный и я просто использовал Returns. Можете подсказать как работать с этим, если метод асинхронный? Пробую через ReturnsAsync, но пока что как-то не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ReturnsAsync` должен работать. Что значит `пока что как-то не работает`? Вместо `ReturnsAsync` можете попробовать `Returns(Task.FromResult(GetBaseReservations()))`

Comment: попробовал как вы сказали, не работает. прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на текст ошибки: У вас метод `GetBaseReservations()` возвращает тип `Reservation`, отличный от того, что ожидает "мокаемый" метод. Первый возвращает `Entities.Reservation`, второй - `Entities.Postgres.Reservation`

Comment: заработало спасибо, моя ошибка